# swing event filter

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to install filter for events for all controls placed in some container?

For example I have a panel where two buttons live and one panel with two text boxes, I want to be able to receive all events that go to these controls (buttons and text boxes).

**UPD**
There are four controls:

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JButton b1 = new JButton();
JButton b2 = new JButton();
mainPanel.add(b1, BorderLayout.WEST);
mainPanel.add(b2, BorderLayout.EAST);

JPanel childPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JTextField txt1 = new JTextField();
JTextField txt2 = new JTextField();
childPanel.add(txt1);
childPanel.add(txt2);
mainPanel.add(childPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

EventDispatchingMachine.attachEventListener(mainPanel, listener);
```

where `listener` receives all events that go to b1, b2, txt1, txt2. Ideally every event that could be processed via listener on specific control (e.g. b1.addActionListener(asd)) I want to receive in `listener`.

Comment: please post here http://sscce.org/, then maybe I could be my answer more valuable

Comment: for/what is EventDispatchingMachine?

Comment: @kleopatra, that is imaginary class for attaching event listener that receives events sent to other controls that has `mainPanel` as their parent (direct or through other containers e.g. `txt1` control)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jdk7 you can use JLayer to decorate any component with listeners:

```
    LayerUI<JComponent> ui = new LayerUI<JComponent>() {

        @Override
        protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JComponent> l) {
             System.out.println(e.getSource().getClass() + " at " + e.getPoint());
        } 
    };
    JLayer<JComponent> layer = new JLayer<JComponent>(mainPanel, ui);
    layer.setLayerEventMask(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK );
```

(for jdk6, there's the project JXLayer which supports the same)

**Edit**

on second reading of the question, the answer could be "not possible": event != event. You can (via a LayerUI or manually AWTEventListener) register to receive all events that are globally dispatched. You cannot hook into "locally" dispatched events, as f.i. actionEvents which are simply used as parameters to a known callback method which is called directly by the sender.

Answer (score 2):

you have look at [EventListenerList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html), then you can take all Listener into Array,

Comment: @misha nesterenko before anything not possible change order of firing Listeners in Swing,

Comment: do you want http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/UseEventListenerListtostoreeventlistenerlist.htm, then inside GroupListener determine source and class ???, I have to question are you want to collecting these events for logging & tracing or you can manage of accesses for concrete user or Object ???, because there I see most important differencies,

Comment: I do not want to store, I just need somehow receive all events that are intended for controls that has specified parent _before_ they go to their controls.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to intercept events before they are dispatched to a component then check out [Global Event Dispatching](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/06/global-event-dispatching/).

If you just want to listen for all events then check out [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/).

In both cases you would need to check the source of the event to determine if it is for a component on the panel.

However, I believe, this will not catch an ActionEvent because this in not a system event but a Java generated event for a mousePressed/mouseReleased on a specific component.

If we knew the reason for the filtering then maybe we could provide an alternate approach. For example maybe you are trying to create a [Disabled Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/disabled-panel/)?